# How can i add a row between each row in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I'm trying to find out how I can add a row between each row in `data.frame`. For example:

```
xdf <- data.frame(name = c(letters[1:5]),
              w1 = runif(5, min = 1, max = 10),
              w2 = runif(5, min = 10, max = 20))

name       w1       w2
1    a 7.217998 14.51789
2    b 6.583311 13.01331
3    c 1.655201 18.83256
4    d 1.117273 19.81330
5    e 2.925724 13.21518
```

So, we assume that our row is just 5th row is e and what i'm saying is:

```
name       w1       w2
1    a 7.217998 14.51789
     e 2.925724 13.21518
2    b 6.583311 13.01331
     e 2.925724 13.21518
3    c 1.655201 18.83256
     e 2.925724 13.21518
4    d 1.117273 19.81330
     e 2.925724 13.21518
5    e 2.925724 13.21518
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

We can `rbind` the sequence of rows with the last row (`nrow`), concatenate (`c`), use that to subset the dataset, remove the last row with `head`, and set the row names to NULL.

```
`row.names<-`(head(xdf[c(rbind(1:nrow(xdf), nrow(xdf))),],-1), NULL)
#   name       w1       w2
#1    a 7.217998 14.51789
#2    e 2.925724 13.21518
#3    b 6.583311 13.01331
#4    e 2.925724 13.21518
#5    c 1.655201 18.83256
#6    e 2.925724 13.21518
#7    d 1.117273 19.81330
#8    e 2.925724 13.21518
#9    e 2.925724 13.21518
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a combination of `apply` and `rbind` from base:

```
do.call(rbind,apply(xdf, 1,function(x) rbind(x,xdf[5,])))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do the same using matrix indexing:

```
m <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(xdf)*2-1, ncol = ncol(xdf), dimnames = list(NULL, names(xdf)))
m[c(T,F),] <- as.matrix(xdf) # odd indices
m[c(F,T),] <- as.matrix(xdf[rep(5, nrow(xdf)-1),]) # even indices
data.frame(m)

  # name       w1       w2
# 1    a 7.217998 14.51789
# 2    e 2.925724 13.21518
# 3    b 6.583311 13.01331
# 4    e 2.925724 13.21518
# 5    c 1.655201 18.83256
# 6    e 2.925724 13.21518
# 7    d 1.117273 19.81330
# 8    e 2.925724 13.21518
# 9    e 2.925724 13.21518
```

---

**Benchmarking**

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
xdf <- data.frame(name = c(letters[1:5]),
              w1 = runif(5, min = 1, max = 10),
              w2 = runif(5, min = 10, max = 20))

f_989 <- function(xdf){
    m <- matrix("", nrow = nrow(xdf)*2-1, ncol = ncol(xdf), 
dimnames = list(NULL, names(xdf)))
    m[c(T,F),] <- as.matrix(xdf)
    m[c(F,T),] <- as.matrix(xdf[rep(5, 4),])
    data.frame(m)
}

f_akrun <- function(xdf) `row.names<-`(head(xdf[c(rbind(1:nrow(xdf), 
nrow(xdf))),],-1), NULL)

f_jamieRowen <- function(xdf) do.call(rbind,apply(xdf, 1,function(x) rbind(x,xdf[5,])))

microbenchmark(f_akrun(xdf), f_989(xdf), f_jamieRowen(xdf))

# Unit: microseconds
              # expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
      # f_akrun(xdf)   89.240  109.3715  118.7190  113.879  126.348  248.188   100
        # f_989(xdf)  417.353  447.4000  495.6733  459.869  482.555 1521.879   100
 # f_jamieRowen(xdf) 1216.902 1262.1230 1303.2455 1298.930 1332.883 1471.100   100
```

Comment: Nice additional info with the benchmarking. Makes akrun's answer look pretty impressive. Not surprised mine is the slowest, although in my opinion (and purely my opinion) my answer is the easiest to follow. Kudos on another neat answer. This turned out to be a more interesting question than I initially thought. If I was being mega picky though I would suggest using `TRUE` and `FALSE` would be much safer than `T` and `F`. Anyway upvote from me.

Comment: To add to my previous comment it would be interesting to know how the solutions scale with size in terms of benchmarking. I can safely rule mine out of ever being fastest but would be interesting to see how the relative performance changes with the size of the initial data frame

Comment: I'd suspect the @akrun's solution would be the winner in larger scales either. Just a side remark, in your solution, you add one extra row (i.e. the result of your answer does have one row more than that of the other two)

Comment: Yes I had noticed that after posting, but since other solutions came along that were better I didn't get round to editing. A quick benchmark suggests that @akrun's solution does scale better, however only very slightly. With mine being terrible because of `apply` and the millions of calls to `rbind`.

Comment: Yes, in fact, apply family functions are just normal loops but in compact syntax.